# Calculate the norm of matrix

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, normed-spaces

A norm of a matrix is define as below :

$$
|M| = \sup_{|x| = 1} |Mx|
$$

where $|x| = |x|_2$ is a 2-norm.

I want to calculate the norm of a matrix :

$$
M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3\\ 
 4 & 5 & 6\\ 
 7 & 8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I know **Lagrange Multiplier** can solve $|M|$, but this matrix has a property :

$$ \det(M) = 0 $$

, so I wondering if there is any other special method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume $|x|$ is the Euclidean norm. Then
$$|Mx|^2=(Mx)^t(Mx^t)=x^t(M^tM)x.$$
The matrix $A=M^tM$ is symmetric, and so diagonalisable by an
orthogonal matrix. It follows that $x^tAx$ has maximum $\lambda$
over $\{x:|x|=1\}$ where $\lambda$ is the largest eigenvalue of $A$.